# Pass Objects to another Object

Tags: vb.net, oop

If I use an object2 inside object1, is it good practice to pass object1 ByRef, so I can use Object1's properties? Or, is there a better way to pass data between the two? Here would be an example:

```
Class Object1

private m_width as integer

Public Sub1()
    dim newObj2 as new Object2(Object1)
End Sub

End Class
```

or would my only way to do it is like this:

```
Class Object1

private m_width as integer

Public Sub1()
    dim newObj2 as new Object2()
    nexObj2.width = m_width
End Sub

End Class
```

If I do it the second approach and I have a lot of properties, then it seems to defeat the purpose?

Comment: What's "the purpose"? In other words, can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `ByVal` or `ByRef` doesn't matter when passing classes as they're reference types. Also, `New Object2(Object1)` won't work. To refer to the current class use `Me`: `New Object2(Me)`.

Comment: @prprcupofcoffee: I guess what I'm looking for is the best way to use Object1's data in Object2's methods?

Comment: The best way way depends on the specifics of the situation.  We can't tell you what to do in any specific case based on a contrived example.  What you should do is think about these things as real-world objects and decide whether it makes sense that one of them owns the other or whether it makes more sense that they are separate and simply exchange data.  The answer will be different between cases.